# Installing the correct DLLs to resolve ActionLink(...) and RouteLink(...) in a cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, intellisense, actionlink, routelink

I'm having an extremely hard time to get `@Html.ActionLink(...)` and/or `@Html.RouteLink(...)` to be resolved in my cshtml view, which should become part of an MVC5 AngularJS webapplication. I didn't expect it to be that hard.
This matter is really driving me crazy.

I have tried:

- installing (by Nuget or other method),
- uninstalling,
- starting a new MVC project from scratch,
- vs2013Pro/vs2015 community edition.

The only thing I haven't try yet is switching to another computer. But so far, I always end up that these 2 helper methods not being resolved in my cshtml view, regardless of the arguments added.

I have had *moments* that one or both of the above helpers were being resolved by Visual Studio successfully in IntelliSense, but for some reason, when I try to do further useful steps or even just save the project, the active DLLs are switched again, and IntelliSense stops working, and browser execution fails there. Also ViewBag is most of the time unresolved. But that's less important in my case.

It even seems like some agent always makes the DLLs that I need vanish, and replace it by always the same incomplete or old dll versions. I can't get this under my control.

My cshtml view starts like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My main view page";
    Layout = "MyLayout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
@model AngularMVCWebsite.Models.MySituationMode
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <script>
    ...
```

and so on. @Html itself is no problem to resolve.

I may need to take into account that some DLLs are obsolete and replaced by others. But what's a good set of DLLs and their latest good versions? Maybe I can install all at once using a specific recent nuget install? From there I probably can continue without further help.

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

The main thing is to get the proper dlls in place and active and make sure that they stay in place after saving and quitting VS2015/VS2013.

Any educated help much appreciated.

Comment: By any chance, do you use and have JetBrains Resharper installed, and is a ASP.NET Core project that you are creating?

Comment: Maybe the core of the problem is: why can't I at least see the nuget installed dll versions in the project references choice panes?

Comment: And no, I didn't install Resharper. I don't fully understand your question about if I created an ASP.Net Core project: I simply used the standard way to create an MVC project and intend to use AngularJS also. I assume if I use VS2015, the MVC version is automaticallly at least MVC5.

Comment: The reason why I asked is because I had the exact same issue you described and it was caused by Resharper not supporting the ASP.NET core version my project was configured for and resulted in resharper breaking intellisense. If you mean the standard way to create an MVC project is by using the templates in Visual Studio, then that was where my problem originated from because the template targeted an older version by default, even though I had the latest versions of ASP.NET Core installed on my machine. But since you don't have Resharper installed, this is unlikely your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the lastest Mvc Nuget Package?

If it is already installed please update it.

From your console:
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3

Or you can install it from nugget directly.

Comment: Yes, I used the latest Mvc Nuget Package, indeed 5.2.3. I will try to do this again next Friday. Maybe on another machine.

Comment: But why can't I at least see the nuget installed dll versions in the project references choice panes?

Answer (score 0):

I continued with this project on a W10 computer, leaving the Windows 7 environment,
and all behaved much more as expected.
I still believe it should be possible to develop the web  mvc5 razor application on W7, given the correct installation of extras, but I have no time to experiment with that any more. Anyway, maybe others can tell what more should be installed on W7 (Professional ed) to allow vs2013/2015 mvc5 razor web development.